Operation by group in R
I am trying to create a variable in R based on grouped data, but I cannot find a solution. Basically, I have a dataset with this form:
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5),
  group = c('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B'),
  value1 = c('m', 'm', 'f', 'm', 'f', 'm', 'f', 'm'),
  value2 = c(50, 50, 20, 50, 20, 50, 60, 20),
  value1_1 = c('f', 'f', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'f'),
  value2_1 = c(20, 20, 50, 50, 50, 50, 20, 60)
)

Now, I would like to do the following: within every group, I would like to check if each of the row has value1 (of the row itself) == to value1_1 of any other row in the group (excluding the row itself) AND value2 (of the row itself) == to value2_1 of any other row in the group (excluding the row itself). I would like then to create a variable "other_id" which takes, for each row for which this condition is verified, the value of the id of the "matching" row, and NA otherwise. This is what I have up to now:
df <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(other_id = ifelse(value1 %in% value1_1 & value2 %in% value2_1, id, NA)) %>% 
  ungroup()

Now, there are two issues here that I cannot solve: 1) The code does include the row itself, so the match can be found in the same row, which is something I do not want. 2) The variable other_id is made of the ids of each row. Instead, I would like it to contain the id of the matched row (i.e. the one with value1_1 and value2_1 matching.
This is what I would like to obtain:
df <- data.frame(
id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5), 
group = c('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B'), 
value1 = c('m', 'm', 'f', 'm', 'f', 'm', 'f', 'm'), 
value2 = c(50, 50, 20, 50, 20, 50, 60, 20), 
value1_1 = c('f', 'f', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'f'), 
value2_1 = c(20, 20, 50, 50, 50, 50, 20, 60), 
other_id = c("2,3", "2,3", "1", "3", "1", "2", "5", "4"))

Any idea on how can I achieve that?
Thank you in advance, hope my problem is clear enough!

Are f and m defined variables? I presume you meant "f" and "m".

From what I understand so far, it sounds like row 1 should match rows 3, 4, and 5. You mention "the matched row" which might imply you only expect one match? My first thought was to try df <- df |> mutate(row = row_number()); df |>  left_join(df, join_by(group,  value1 == value1_1,  value2 == value2_1)) |>  filter(row.x != row.y) but due to multiple matches the 8 rows become 20...

Thank you both for your answers. @JonSpring you are right, they should have been "f", "m", I now edited the code. In case the matches are multiple, I would like to get all the matched ids (based on my data, I expect it to happen in few cases).

df <- df |> mutate(row = row_number())
df |>
  left_join(df |> select(group, value1_1, value2_1, other_id = id, row), 
            join_by(group, 
                    value1 == value1_1, 
                    value2 == value2_1)) |>
  filter(row.x != row.y)

Result, where row.x represents the row in the original data frame, and row.y is the row it is matched with.
   id group value1 value2 value1_1 value2_1 row.x other_id row.y
1   1     A      m     50        f       20     1        2     3
2   1     A      m     50        f       20     1        2     4
3   1     A      m     50        f       20     1        3     5
4   1     A      m     50        f       20     1        3     6
5   1     A      m     50        f       20     2        2     3
6   1     A      m     50        f       20     2        2     4
7   1     A      m     50        f       20     2        3     5
8   1     A      m     50        f       20     2        3     6
9   2     A      f     20        m       50     3        1     1
10  2     A      f     20        m       50     3        1     2
11  2     A      m     50        m       50     4        2     3
12  2     A      m     50        m       50     4        3     5
13  2     A      m     50        m       50     4        3     6
14  3     A      f     20        m       50     5        1     1
15  3     A      f     20        m       50     5        1     2
16  3     A      m     50        m       50     6        2     3
17  3     A      m     50        m       50     6        2     4
18  3     A      m     50        m       50     6        3     5
19  4     B      f     60        m       20     7        5     8
20  5     B      m     20        f       60     8        4     7


library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(other_id = pmap(list(value1, value2, row_number()), \(v1, v2, rn) {
    id[discard(which(v1 == value1_1 & v2 == value2_1), ~ .x == rn)]
  }), .by = group) |>
  unnest_longer(other_id)

Output
      id group value1 value2 value1_1 value2_1 other_id
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1 A     m          50 f              20        2
 2     1 A     m          50 f              20        2
 3     1 A     m          50 f              20        3
 4     1 A     m          50 f              20        3
 5     1 A     m          50 f              20        2
 6     1 A     m          50 f              20        2
 7     1 A     m          50 f              20        3
 8     1 A     m          50 f              20        3
 9     2 A     f          20 m              50        1
10     2 A     f          20 m              50        1
11     2 A     m          50 m              50        2
12     2 A     m          50 m              50        3
13     2 A     m          50 m              50        3
14     3 A     f          20 m              50        1
15     3 A     f          20 m              50        1
16     3 A     m          50 m              50        2
17     3 A     m          50 m              50        2
18     3 A     m          50 m              50        3
19     4 B     f          60 m              20        5
20     5 B     m          20 f              60        4


df <- mutate(df, row = row_number())
df |>  
  left_join(df, join_by(group,  value1 == value1_1,  value2 == value2_1), relationship = "many-to-many") |>  
  filter(row.x != row.y, id.x != id.y) |>
  group_by(row = row.x, id = id.x, group, value1, value2, value1_1, value2_1) %>%
  summarize(other_id = toString(unique(id.y)), .groups = "drop")

This?
